# How to update elements on a page Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Hi I'm trying to submit a DOB on a website the website uses a date picker I'm  using puppeteer so far I have been able to submit the value by using :

```
await page.waitFor(1000);
await page.$eval('input[name=dateOfBirth]', el => el.click());
await page.$eval('input[name=dateOfBirth]', el => el.value = '1999-06-09');
```

but the element wont update unless I manually click it even running .click on it again wont work any idea's on what the problem could be.

Comment: Are you sure your element is selected? Can you log the "el" variable? I have a suspicion that your selector is incorrect. It should be: input[name="dateOfBirth"]

Comment: <input id="99ad8dc5-0b12-4310-825c-1ece91663495" type="date" 
 placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" name="dateOfBirth" data- 
 componentname="dateOfBirth" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" 
 autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" data-ddlabel="dd" data-mmlabel="mm" 
    data-yyyylabel="yyyy>                                                                                                                                  
This is the element in question I think I have the right one selected because if I manually click the page after the input is filled it updates to the filled info

Comment: Have you tried using `page.click(selector)`?

Comment: Oh Gosh, now I see it. Change the order mate

Comment: Ive tried page.click() but the ID is randomly generated and ive also added another page.$eval().click() and that didn't work either